# ConcurrentHashMap to HashMap

Tags: java, gwt

I am just wondering... How to cast `ConcurrentHashMap` to `HashMap` in an optimal way?

Any useful comment is much appreciated

Comment: Why do you believe that is necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you need to do that?  Just cast it to a `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

A `ConcurrentHashMap` is not a `HashMap` (in the strict class inheritance sense), so you *cannot* perform this cast. Like Keith says, you're probably better off treating it like a `Map` and having your client code not care about the implementation. If you really want to turn a `ConcurrentHashMap` into a `HashMap`, use the constructor [HashMap(Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28java.util.Map%29), but this requires creating & populating a whole new Map.

I'll clarify my "treating it like a `Map`" suggestion. The usual way you'd write code (unless you really need features unique to `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` is like this:

```
Map<K, V> myMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

or

```
Map<K, V> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>():
```

but not

```
//Don't do this unless you have a good reason!
HashMap<K, V> myMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
```

The advantage of keeping things general and defining the variable `myMap` as being a `Map` instead of a `HashMap` is that it lets you change the implementation you use, worry-free.

Comment: +1 Thank you too for more details